# Can't run old swift project after XCode 6 beta 4 installation

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

I've installed xcode 6 beta 4 and today all my old projects don't appear at the launch of xcode between recent projects (the list is empty instead). So i click directly in the project file and everything started.

My project is in Swift and, after a lot of strange errors, with some corrections i can build again the code and execute it in iOS Simulator and it works as i wish.
The big problems come when i try to run the project in my physical device (ipad Air and iPhone 4s both updated to iOS 8 beta 4).

When i run the project in my iPhone Xcode returns this runtime error:

[image]

And when i run the project in my iPad Air Xcode returns this error:

[image]

i've tryed a clean instalation of XCode and i've searched everywhere. I'm very frustrated because it works on iOS simulator and i don't know what to do with this kind of error, i don't know where searching or what searching for.

Comment: At what point does it fail? Have you put breakpoints in `main`? In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`? Do you get it with all projects or just this one?

Comment: There's no breakpoint and i've just tryed to create a new project with a simple view and a label and it runs on the phone. I'dont know what piece of code sends this runtime error and i don't know how search it. Also, xcode it's strange when it start because neither the new project is shown in the recent project list.

Comment: I've just suggested two breakpoints that could help you narrow down the problem. Right now we know _nothing_ about your project. There is no way that we can help you debug it without more information.

Comment: I've putted breakpoints in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: but nothing it still crashes with the same error. Has i said i don't know what to do, i don't know how find the problematic piece. I think it's a problem about some setting or some corrupted file.

Comment: As i thought it was a problem of XCode configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of tentative i've found a solution: i had to delete Derived Data. The steps are: in XCode Window -> Organizer -> Projects -> selected the interested project -> click the delete button in Derived Data

Answer (score 0):

Deleting DerivedData is not enough - you have to delete ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode* directories to prevent this one from happening. Do that with every beta upgrade.